Using VBA-WEB and getting error when parsing JSON
I am trying to send a JSON formatted request using the VBA-WEB library to a FedEx API and am getting the error below:

ERROR - WebHelpers.ParseByFormat: 11000, An error occurred during parsing
10001: Error parsing JSON:
?


ERROR - WebHelpers.ParseByFormat: 11000, An error occurred during parsing
10001: Error parsing JSON:
?
?       Ñj?0?ïûÁë*:mw'ê¨ÆLÝ ?!irZ??¸$?Ié»OÓÎÝm;Wÿ?ÿ|?óãE?¦Ì´RdÜy@ND²Ç¦ziª-??ú3Kî?¿¡îü?òãÒûUè?þ~µæï3¾v?×6PJ*=Ö¼Z?æ<'»Á$?éLµÍIK/.pÅõ«ã(O?2.ráÝ^?>=ge?ÜÌ5hM¶)?]OÅ?iH*Ô?ÒRXj5Rðqjp?w Ð©çÔ ¢?#£D´?3?_??ÿ?zN¾ý-§9©w¿?«?ÄÍ?IaÆÏ_yt?®7Ã¿Emz[\¾  _.È

The API I am communicating wants to receive the request formatted as JSON.
I have looked up the error and found it occurs when JSON is not formatted correctly.
I have checked the format of my JSON using multiple online checker and all came back saying my JSON was valid. So the error is coming from something else.
I have found other postings on similar topics but they seem to use: Request.Format = WebFormat.JSON, where as I am using Request.ContentType = "application/JSON". I have tried both methods and both return the same error.
If someone can see where I may be going wrong that would be much appreciated.
I have attached my code below.
Let me know if there is any additional information I can provide.
Public Sub API()

    ' CREATING CLIENT 
    Dim Client As New WebClient
    Client.BaseUrl = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com"
    
    ' CREATING REQUEST
    Dim Request As New WebRequest
    
    ' DEFINING HEADERS
    Request.Resource = "/ship/v1/shipments"
    Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpPost
    Request.ContentType = "application/json"
    Request.Accept = "application/json"
    Request.AddHeader "Authorization", "Bearer XXX"

    ' REQUEST BODY SCHEMA
    Dim Body as New Scripting.Dictionary
    ' Request body schema is pasted bellow

    Set Request.Body = Body
    
    ' CREATE RESPONSE
    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)
    
    ' CHECK
    Debug.Print Response.Content ' Print out entire response

End Sub

Request Body being sent:
{
  "requestedShipment": {
    "shipper": {
      "address": {
        "streetLines": [
          "12 Sesame Street"
        ],
        "city": "Toronto",
        "countryCode": "CA"
      },
      "contact": {
        "phoneNumber": "1112223333"
      }
    },
    "recipients": [
      {
        "address": {
          "streetLines": [
            "123 10th Street"
          ],
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "countryCode": "US"
        },
        "contact": {
          "phoneNumber": "3334445555"
        }
      }
    ],
    "pickupType": "CONTACT_FEDEX_TO_SCHEDULE",
    "serviceType": "INTERNATIONAL_FIRST",
    "packagingType": "FEDEX_BOX",
    "shippingChargesPayment": {
      "paymentType": "SENDER"
    },
    "labelSpecification": {
      "labelStockType": "PAPER_4x6",
      "imageType": "PDF"
    },
    "requestedPackageLineItems": [
      {
        "weight": {
          "units": "KG",
          "value": 22.22
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "labelResponseOptions": "URL_ONLY",
  "accountNumber": {
    "value": "123456789"
  }
}


Which line has the error?

The code runs completely. The 'Response.Content' returns nothing. The error that I have highlight occurs due to the function ParseByFormat in the module WebHelpers.

I'm not sure this question can be answered without a complete and reproducible example. [mcve] -- And yes, I realize this will be difficult with your issue.

If your code runs completely at what point does the error pop up?  Is the parse error on the request or on the response?

Its on the response.

Looks like the server is not returning an appropriate response (binary? compressed?).  Have you tried this using "plain" XMLHTTP POST method, and if so does that give something different as a response?

It is giving me a 400 error, with that same error as I have shown above

What is "it" here?  The plain XMLHTTP method?  On which line?

Sorry I just added a print statement for 'Response.StatusCode' and Response.StatusDescription' to see if it would give me a bit more information on what was happening. When I did that is what returned me the "400 - bad request" error. Additionally using the XMLHTTP method does not get rid of the 11000 error I have been getting.

I think it's pretty difficult for anyone here to be able to figure this out without access to your API endpoint, or without knowing more detail about the expected request format, and what you're actually sending.

I am trying to communicate with a FedEx API.  I have attached the request body I am sending. Hopefully this helps. Thank you for your help thus far

Difficult for me to test anything, since I don't have a Fedex account.  Maybe some here does.
